# Как объяснить другу ТСЯ и ТЬСЯ

Tags: глаголы, мягкий-знак

Несколько раз уже объяснял другу как узнать ставить `Ь` или нет в ТЬСЯ способом "что делатЬ / что сделатЬ" - то ставится, "что делает / что сделает" - не ставится, но он все равно не понимает, может есть какой-то другой вариант?

Comment: Можно не объяснять, а показать предложенный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

**«ТСЯ» И «ТЬСЯ» В ГЛАГОЛАХ**

Неопределенная или личная форма глагола? Обычно для проверки мы задаем вопросы. «Что делает – что делать» – очень простое решение. А что мы вообще-то **проверяем?**

**1. ПОСТАНОВКА ЗАДАЧИ**

(1) Данная орфограмма для **самых простых грамматических** конструкций начинает изучаться уже в начальной школе, в дальнейшем особое внимание обращается на более **сложные** грамматические конструкции, в которых делается выбор ТСЯ или ТЬСЯ.

Недостатком обычных учебников является то, что **фонетические предпосылки** орфограммы обычно не указываются.

(2) Причиной орфограммы является встреча **зубных согласных Т и С,** при этом формы ***ТСЯ*** и ***ТЬСЯ*** произносятся как ***ЦА*** и не различаются на слух, например: *ошибаться и ошибается, отправляться и отправляется.*

**2. «ШКОЛЬНАЯ» ПРОВЕРКА**

Личная или неопределенная форма глагола?

**(1) ФОРМА «ТСЯ»**

Форма ***ТСЯ*** соответствует личной форме глагола в 3-ем лице ед. и мн. числа и проверяется **вопросами**: он **(что делает?)** одевается, они (**что делают?**) одеваются – **личные** формы глагола, *Ь* не пишется.

**ТЕКСТОВЫЕ ПРИМЕРЫ**

Зачем покинул он меня и скоро ль возвратится?

Мне не спится, не лежится.

**(2) Форма «ТЬСЯ»**

Форма ***ТЬСЯ*** соответствует **неопределённой форме** глагола и проверяется с помощью вопроса: надо (***что делать?***) одеваться – **неопределенная** форма глагола, Ь пишется.

**ТЕКСТОВЫЕ ПРИМЕРЫ**

Звезды стали туманиться и терять свою лучистость.

Кое-как удалось разлучиться и постылый огонь потушить.

Ни слова не сказала я, за что ж ему сердиться?

**3. ДРУГИЕ СПОСОБЫ ПРОВЕРКИ**

(1) Проверку форм ТСЯ и ТЬСЯ можно также сделать, если убрать из данной глагольной формы частицу ***СЯ***, так как зубный звук С является **ПРИЧИНОЙ** орфограммы, например: ***надо одеваться – надо одевать.***

(2) Также следует отметить, что две формы (инфинитив и личная форма) **редко совпадают полностью** (случиться – случится), но чаще всего отличаются – **по морфемному составу или по ударению:** реш***А***ться – реш***АЕТ***ся, приходИться – прихОдится.

(3) **Грамматический способ**

В старших классах изучаются виды сказуемых и предложений. Надо различать **простое и составное** глагольное сказуемое, например:

***Нужно одеваться** теплее.*  Односоставное безличное предложение, составное глагольное сказуемое.

*Он быстро **одевается**.* Двусоставное предложение, простое глагольное сказуемое.

Comment: Sharon, ну правда, простите, ну как вас не критиковать? Первые два пункта о том, что и так знает автор вопроса. Пункт 3 "ДРУГИЕ СПОСОБЫ ПРОВЕРКИ" содержит следующие термины: зубный звук С, инфинитив и личная форма, морфемный состав, простое и составное глагольное сказуемое, односоставное безличное предложение, двусоставное предложение. Если друг не понимает простой, школьной проверки, то какой способ предлагаете вы?

Comment: Да вы не стесняйтесь, критикуйте и минусуйте. Друг? Но мы его плохо знаем, возможно, у него высшее образование, а это правило он не понимает. Вот что тут делать! И еще: мы должны рассчитывать не только на друга, но и на всю нашу аудиторию, не так ли? Так вы знаете  4-й дополнительный способ объяснения орфограммы?

Comment: Я не минусую. Только в особо исключительных случаях и не вас. Высшее образование (оно бывает разным – эффективным, специальным, проплаченным, для галочки...) ничего не гарантирует. Но если человек не врубается в простой синтаксис и грамматику, не чувствует язык, то нужен более лёгкий способ объяснить. Я такого пока не знаю, к сожалению. Поэтому отвечать прежде всего нужно на запрос, а не на всю аудиторию.

Comment: Ладно, про друга не будем говорить.  Вы критикуете, а участники минусуют с учетом вашей критики.  И про аудиторию скажите: такой общий ОБЗОР никому здесь не нужен?  Вроде бы форум лингвистов и любителей словесности...  Вы меня не перестаете сегодня удивлять.

Comment: Да мало у нас минусов. Не думаю, что мои комментарии сильно влияют на это. Обзор не помешает, но в отдельном вопросе. Вы же часто после каких-либо обсуждений задаёте свой вопрос по теме. А здесь Руслану нужен такой способ, чтобы донести наконец-то смысл орфограммы.

Comment: Минусы мне ставят, да еще Лео (за неправильные вопросы и ответы).  А друг пусть  СЯ уберет, тогда услышит ТЬ или Т (твердый или мягкий звук). Вам это тоже непонятно, объяснять надо? Из моего обзора каждый может что-то выбрать для себя, что в этом плохого. МНЕ же интересно: может, есть еще способы объяснения? Не у вас, так у других. Зачем же сразу и с места меня критиковать? Мне опять вас приходится сравнивать...

Comment: Я не буду больше ничего писать, все уже сказала.

Comment: *Мне пригодится – мне пригодит. Мне хочется – мне хочет. Мне нравится – мне нравит.*  А здесь как быть?

Comment: А вопрос как задать в безличном предложении?  Тогда без грамматического анализа никак, больше ничего не подойдет. Так что выбор есть и обозначен.  И почему я не надо говорить о фонетике, причину орфограммы не все знают.

Comment: Оно (это) что делает? – нравится. Оно (это) что сделает? – пригодится. // Причину орфограммы не все знают, но все слышат!

Comment: Но ведь друг не понимает вопросов, что-нибудь другое давайте. Может, они кажутся ему неестественными. Она нравится мне.  Она же ничего не делает, даже не замечает, что нравится.  Так вы предлагаете вопросы и только вопросы?  И ни шагу в сторону.

Comment: Вы спросили, как задать вопрос, а не о непонимающем вопроса друге. Какая разница, что она замечает или не замечает, здесь чисто грамматический, можно сказать, нейтив-вопрос: *она что делает? – нравится мне.*

Comment: Ладно, Александр, мы достаточно сказали друг другу.  Жаль, что вы не дали ответ по заданному вопросу. Высокий рейтинг вашего мнения я вам гарантирую. Но если у меня будет много минусов, то уберу свой ответ.

Comment: Много это сколько? :) Помню только у Джима нашего было где-то 5-6. Кстати, видели, что его заблокировали на 100 (на 100, Карл!) лет?

Comment: У меня норма два минуса. Мне жаль, что у него все так сложилось. Людей с такой энергией и с таким заинтересованным  отношением к языку еще поискать надо.

Comment: А я вас люблю – **следовательно,** ставлю плюс!

Comment: Двое тихо говорили,
Расставались и корили:
«Ты такая…»
«Ты такой!..»
«Ты плохая…»
«Ты плохой!..»
«Уезжаю в Лениград… Как я рада!»
«Как я рад!!!»

Дело было на вокзале,
Дело было этим летом,
Все решили. Все сказали.
Были куплены билеты...  https://rustih.ru/iosif-utkin-tipichnyj-sluchaj/